# Having trouble importing CSV file into PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, csv, pgadmin

I am a beginner with PostgreSQL, I am trying to import a csv file into pgAdmin4, but seem to be having some trouble. I have the CSV file saved on my desktop and there is no header in the CSV file. Here is what my query currently looks like,

```
COPY opioid_csv(Substance, Source, Specific_Measure, Type_event, Region, PRUID, Time_Period, Year_Quarter, Aggregator, Disaggregator, Unit, Value)
FROM 'Users/myusername/Desktop/opioid_csv.csv'
DELIMITER ','
```

I have created a table with all the column names as well but I am getting the following error:

> ERROR:  relation "opioid_csv" does not exist
>  SQL state: 42P01

Comment: To your question add the output of: `select * from pg_tables where tablename  ilike '%opioid_csv%';`.

Comment: 1) FYI, you are not copying into `pgAmin4`, it is just a client. The data is being copied to a table in the Postgres server. 2) You probably should take a look at [Import/Export](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/6.18/import_export_data.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try, using `psql`:

```
postgres=# \dt *.opioid_csv
             List of relations
    Schema    |    Name    | Type  | Owner 
--------------+------------+-------+-------
 marcothesane | opioid_csv | table | marco
(1 row)
```

Very probably, if you *did* succeed to create your `opioid_csv` table, you created it in another schema than `public`. You would have to put the schema (`marcothesane` in my example) before the table name: use `marcothesane.opioid_csv` instead of just `opioid.csv`

Let me try to do it with a CSV file of mine:

```bash
marco ~/1/Vertica/supp $ head test.csv
id,text
1,1VIAgFg
2,IfPLHbT
3,EWOmXAx
4,zl8paoh
5,9EpQ9Kx
6,ZpagcCh
7,6xoVoit
8,mCniu1U
9,euieQZa
```

Matching table DDL - using my own d2l DDL inferrer:

```bash
marco ~/1/Vertica/supp $ d2lm -coldelcomma test.csv | tee test.ddl.sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (
  id   INTEGER NOT NULL
, text CHAR(7) NOT NULL
);
```

Then, I run psql with that newly generated script:

```bash
marco ~/1/Vertica/supp $ psql -af test.ddl.sql 
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (
  id   INTEGER NOT NULL
, text CHAR(7) NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE
```

Then, as I have a header line in my file, I `COPY` with `csv header`:

```bash
marco ~/1/Vertica/supp $ psql -c "copy test from  '/Users/marco/1/Vertica/supp/test.csv' delimiter ',' csv header"
COPY 50000
marco ~/1/Vertica/supp $ psql -c "select count(*) from test"
 count 
-------
 50000
```

What is different from what you do?

Comment: Hi Marco, thanks for the help. The opioid_csv table was created in the public schema